# OpenCL with AMD RX 6900XT on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amd-graphics, amd, opencl

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel version 5.8.0-50-generic) on a system consisting of an i9 9900K, an RX 6900XT and 32GB of RAM. This system is meant to run OpenCL code for a university project, preferably on the GPU.

So far, i have installed the latest Pro Radeon drivers (version 21.10) using
`./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=pal,legacy`, i have installed OpenCL headers using `sudo apt-get install opencl-headers` and i have installed `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` as well as `cl-info` and `glmark`.

Using glmark, I can verify that at least my graphics card is correctly set up for running OpenGL. However, the AMD OpenCL platform contains no devices, i.e.

```
  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices                                 0
```

Is there anything obvious that I missed?

Further information that may be useful: I have also installed `pocl-opencl-icd` which produced a working OpenCL environment and the Intel drivers for my CPU, which doesn't work at the moment (but might get fixed by fixing the AMD platform?)

This installation is not dear to me, I just care for a running OpenCL installation. A fresh install of any other (free) distribution is fine with me, if this is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Radeon RX 6000-cards, the installation command for the proprietary driver (which is necessary for OpenCL) is

```
./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=rocr
```

The arguments for --opencl listed in the AMD installation instructions do not apply (it says for hardware newer than Vega 10, i.e. RX Vega 56 and RX Vega 64 and Vega Frontier Edition, `--opencl=pal` should be used).

To use OpenCL without root permissions, finally use

```
sudo usermod -a -G render $LOGNAME
```

to add your user to the render group. It seems adding the user to the `video` group might in some cases be beneficial, too.